Using the "mount" command to mount a CIFS share referencing a KeyTab file for the credentials
I have an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I have an Active Directory Domain with a CIFS Share
I created a KeyTab file on the Windows Server (for use with Ubuntu)
Using Kinit I can obtain a Kerberos ticket OK referencing the KeyTab file
Now, I want to use the "mount -t cifs" command and I want to specify the "KeyTab" file as the file for mount to fetch the credentials
or get the mount command to automatically pick the existing Kerberos TGT ticket in the cache (i.e. after running Kinit) and use it for authentication
I did not want to put the username and password into fstab file  (as a KeyTab I think is more secure)
Thanks in advance

isn't the way to do this to include something like this in your fstab mount line?credentials=root/.smbcredentials and then create the smbcredentials file in the named directory (it's a hidden file)

Hi Graham
Thanks very much for taking the time to reply, I really appreciate it
I was hoping I would use the KeyTab file and the Kerberos Ticket it generates as I think this is more secure.
I was hoping I could either instruct the Mount command to use the Kerberos ticket already there (after doing the kinit) or tell Mount to read the credentials from the KeyTab file which will kick off Kinit and authenticate
Does anyone know if this is possible please?

" Does anyone know if this is possible please?" sorry, not in my experience but I hope you find an answer although I did find this Q&A from 6 years ago which might give some clues.
